# Active Directory Replication across Sites slow or not working

Tags: active-directory, replication

I've just inherited (isn't it always the way!) a Windows Domain. The domain is spread across 2 sites.

Site01 has 3 DCs & Site02 has 2 DCs.

If I create a user in either site, the other DCs in that site, immediately replicate and show the new user. The new user is not shown in the other site though.

If I manually run the following command, everything syncs and the new user appears:

`repadmin /syncall issdc01 /APed`

In the Inter-Site Transports DEFAULTIPSITELINK the replicate every time value is set to 180 minutes. I thought this was the solution, but on another Windows Domain, this is the same, but replication takes place across sites immediately.

What can I check to resolve this issue? We are running Windows Server 2008

Results of `dcdiag /test:dns` show a server that is no longer part of our domain:

TEST: Delegations (Del)
   Error: DNS server: oldserver.win.domain.com
   IP: [Missing glue A record]

Comment: Which version of Window server are you running?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 64-bit (mix of Enterprise/Standard)

Comment: Post DCDIAG results. You probably have DNS issues.

Comment: Was that oldserver a DC or only domain member?

Comment: I'm not sure as it was before my time, but I suspect it was a DC (although not in AD) as file servers here tend to be DCs too

Comment: You should perform metadata cleanup to remove all traces of long gone DCs (first, make a system state data backup on your DC, just in case). Here is pretty good tutorial: http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm After that, run dcdiag again and see if error persists.

Comment: I tried that (using that exact site) but it doesn't exist....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AD Sites & Services, for the IP transport, I made a server at each site a preferred bridgehead server for that transport.

This added a new "automatically generated" connection for each of those servers.

Replication now occurs within around 30 seconds, even with the replication time set to 180 minutes.

Comment: Can you set DEFAULTIPSITELINK Option back to 0 and see what happens? I believe this option setting overrides replication time setting.

Answer (score 1):

We have set the DEFAULTIPSITELINK to 15 minutes for the replication time.

Local DCs replicate instantly... across different sites, it depends on this replication time.

Change this to 15minutes, create a new users, it will replicate instantly across local DCs, wait 15 minutes, it will replicate across different sites.

Comment: How is this timed? Does it do it every 15 minutes? Or does it do it 15 minutes after a change?

Comment: The sites are replicated every 15 minutes, if you click on 'Change Schedule' you can see when it replicates.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: Right click DEFAULTIPSITELINK, Properties, Attribute Editor, set Options to 0x1

Comment: I've set that and made another new user, but this hasn't replicated either

Comment: check again in few minutes please

Comment: Still not replicating....

Comment: now wait. Did your sites replicate, ever? (before adding this option)

Comment: Yes they did. It seems it was only after the 180 minutes wait. Want it to be a few seconds, rather than minutes though